# Android - SimpleCursorAdapter changeCursor function too slow

Tags: android, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I am looking to find a solution to speeding up updating my spinners. Currently I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter and calling ChangeCursor whenever I change the search conditions based on the previously selected spinner.

I did a bit of timing tests and the queries take from 5ms to 60ms, while the changeCursor function takes between 600ms and 4000ms+. Is there another method to updating the cursor on the adapter that is quicker? I am not using the same query, so I can't simply requery the cursor and then call notifydatasetchanged. I have to create a new query then get a new cursor back (maybe there is a better way to even do this portion).

Here is how I am currently populating

```
private void writerSpinner() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { Passage.COL_WRITER_ID + " " + BaseColumns._ID, Passage.COL_WRITER_NAME };
        String whereClause = null;
        String groupBy = null;
        String orderBy = Passage.COL_WRITER_ID + " ASC";

        if (mAdapterPassage == null) {
            String[] columnsSpinner = new String[] { Passage.COL_WRITER_NAME };
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            mAdapterPassage = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null, columnsSpinner, to);
            mAdapterPassage.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mPassage.setAdapter(mAdapterPassage);
            mPassage.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
        }

        AsyncLoadData loadData = new AsyncLoadData(mAdapterPassage, mPassage, Passage.TABLE_NAME_WRITERS, columns, whereClause, groupBy, orderBy);
        loadData.execute();
    }

    private void updateChapterSpinner() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { Passage.COL_WRITER_ID + " " + BaseColumns._ID, Passage.COL_CHAPTER_ID };
        String whereClause = Passage.COL_WRITER_ID + " = " + mSelectedWriterId;
        String groupBy = Passage.COL_CHAPTER_ID;
        String orderBy = Passage.COL_CHAPTER_ID + " ASC";

        if (mAdapterChapter == null) {
            String[] columnsSpinner = new String[] { Passage.COL_CHAPTER_ID };
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            mAdapterChapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null, columnsSpinner, to);
            mAdapterChapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mChapter.setAdapter(mAdapterChapter);
            mChapter.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
        }

        AsyncLoadData loadData = new AsyncLoadData(mAdapterChapter, mChapter, Passage.TABLE_NAME_PASSAGES, columns, whereClause, groupBy, orderBy);
        loadData.execute();
    }

    private void updateVerseSpinner() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { Passage.COL_WRITER_ID + " " + BaseColumns._ID, Passage.COL_VERSE_ID };
        String whereClause = Passage.COL_WRITER_ID + " = " + mSelectedWriterId
                + " AND " + Passage.COL_CHAPTER_ID + " = " + mSelectedChapter;
        String groupBy = Passage.COL_VERSE_ID;
        String orderBy = Passage.COL_VERSE_ID + " ASC";


        if (mAdapterVerse == null) {
            String[] columnsSpinner = new String[] { Passage.COL_VERSE_ID };
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            mAdapterVerse = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null, columnsSpinner, to);
            mAdapterVerse.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mVerse.setAdapter(mAdapterVerse);
            mVerse.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
        }

        AsyncLoadData loadData = new AsyncLoadData(mAdapterVerse, mVerse, Passage.TABLE_NAME_PASSAGES, columns, whereClause, groupBy, orderBy);
        loadData.execute();
    }

private class AsyncLoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String mTableName; 
        String[] mColumns;
        String mWhereClause;
        String mGroupBy;
        String mOrderBy;
        Spinner mSpinner;
        Cursor mCursor;
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

        public AsyncLoadData(SimpleCursorAdapter adapter, Spinner spinner, String tableName, String[] columns, String whereClause, String groupBy, String orderBy) {
            mAdapter = adapter;
            mSpinner = spinner;
            mTableName = tableName;
            mColumns = columns;
            mWhereClause = whereClause;
            mGroupBy = groupBy;
            mOrderBy = orderBy;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            //mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            long startCursor = new Date().getTime();
            mCursor = mDBHandler.query(mTableName, mColumns, mWhereClause, null, mGroupBy, null, mOrderBy);
            long timeToQuery = new Date().getTime() - startCursor;          

            Log.i("CursorQuery", "Time to Query Cursor " + mGroupBy + ": "  + timeToQuery + "ms");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {   
            long startAdapter = new Date().getTime();
            mAdapter.changeCursor(mCursor);
            long timeToChangeCursor = new Date().getTime() - startAdapter;

            Log.i("AdapterQuery", "Time to Change Cursor " + mGroupBy + ": " + timeToChangeCursor + "ms");

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

private OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch(parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.bible_passage:
                mSelectedWriterId = position + 1;
                updateChapterSpinner();
                break;
            case R.id.bible_chapter:
                mSelectedChapter = position + 1;    
                updateVerseSpinner();
                break;
            case R.id.bible_verse:
                mSelectedVerse = position + 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    };
```

Comment: Remove the `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` line as it is useless because the `changeCursor()` method calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` in its implementation. Are you sure you get those loading values? Try to use traceview to see where is the problem.

Comment: @Luksprog Sorry there is no problem within the code, it all functions as intended. It is just not very fast. The changecursor takes 1/2 to 4 seconds of time to change the data in my cursor adapter and this is undesirable. I am looking for a solution that is quicker.

Comment: I wasn't saying that the code is incorrect(but that line is useless). I don't see another method to update the `Cursor`(`swapCursor`, but there shouldn't be a difference). Use the traceview to see where is the bottleneck. Also it will be worth mentioning if you tested and seen this problem only on certain API levels or it's general.

Comment: @DMan did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @BruceConnor Unfortunately no I was unable to find a quicker method of performing the operation. The limitation seems to come from the hardware. Running the above on an S2 was almost instant every time, but on slower hardware (such as an Ace) it was performing slow.

Comment: The bottleneck for me was that `getCount` needed to build the entire cursor result,  which was slow (~2 seconds) even on my Nexus 4 (for a resul of ~ 50000). I think I just managed to get around this, my times are on the order of 100ms now. I'll post it here in a few days  once I make sure it's not too buggy.

Comment: @BruceConnor Awesome that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

## The Problem

The reason `changeCursor` takes so long is that the cursor returned by
`Database.query(...)` only initializes when it's necessary (so it's
the cursor's fault, not the adapter's).

The reason the cursor is slow to initialize is that it parses the
entire result set at once (because it needs to know the total count).
Even though SQLite returns huge queries really fast, java is very slow
to parse them (100 to 1000 times slower then SQLite).

## The Solution

Come in, [HugeSQLiteCursor](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/HugeSQLiteCursor) ([with JavaDoc!](http://bruce-connor.github.io/HugeSQLiteCursor/)).
I wrote this cursor to solve this problem. It loads the results 
incrementally and automatically, not all at once (with a clever
workaround to find out the total count with nearly 0 overhead).

[Download the `.jar` file](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/HugeSQLiteCursor/raw/master/hugesqlitecursor.jar),
add it to your `libs/` folder, and do something like the following to
use it (the fully qualified name is `com.malabarba.hugesqlitecursor.HugeSQLiteCursor`):

```
adapter.changeCursor(new HugeSQLiteCursor(db, stepSize,
                                          table, columnFields,
                                          selection, selectionArgs));
```

As you can see, because the results are loaded lazily, you need to
pass the database and the query parameters to the constructor.
Once created, the cursor should work perfectly in any situation you
were previously using SQLiteCursor.

The second argument (`stepSize`), is the number of items you want to
be initially loaded when the cursor is created. **This is the important
parameter**.

**The initialization time of the entire cursor will be effectively the
same as if it had only `stepSize` results.** But don't make `stepSize` smaller then the numbers of results which fit in one screen.

This Cursor effectively eliminates the "Java is too slow" bottleneck. 
On my Nexus 4 it returns queries of 50.000 results in less than **60ms**, as opposed to SQLiteCursor which took ~1000ms.
Of course, if your queries are so gigantic that even SQLite is slow to return the results, then this cursor will only get you so far.